# ARM GCC produces unaligned STRD

Tags: c, gcc, memory, arm

I am using GCC to compile a program for an ARM Cortex M3.
My program results in a hardfault, and I am trying to troubleshoot it.

GCC version is `10.3.1` but I have confirmed this with older versions too (i.e. `9.2`).

*The hardfault occurs only when optimizations are enabled (`-O3`).*

The problematic function is the following:

```c
void XTEA_decrypt(XTEA_t * xtea, uint32_t data[2])
{
    uint32_t d0 = data[0];
    uint32_t d1 = data[1];
    uint32_t sum = XTEA_DELTA * XTEA_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS;

    for (int i = XTEA_NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS; i != 0; i--)
    {
        d1 -= (((d0 << 4) ^ (d0 >> 5)) + d0) ^ (sum + xtea->key[(sum >> 11) & 3]);
        sum -= XTEA_DELTA;
        d0 -= (((d1 << 4) ^ (d1 >> 5)) + d1) ^ (sum + xtea->key[sum & 3]);
    }

    data[0] = d0;
    data[1] = d1;
}
```

I noticed that the fault happens in line:

```c
    data[0] = d0;
```

Disassembling this, gives me:

```
49          data[0] = d0;
0000f696:   lsrs    r0, r3, #5
0000f698:   eor.w   r0, r0, r3, lsl #4
0000f69c:   add     r0, r3
0000f69e:   ldr.w   r12, [sp, #4]
0000f6a2:   eors    r5, r0
0000f6a4:   subs    r2, r2, r5
0000f6a6:   strd    r2, r3, [r12]
0000f6aa:   add     sp, #12
0000f6ac:   ldmia.w sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, pc}
0000f6b0:   ldr     r3, [sp, #576]  ; 0x240
0000f6b2:   b.n     0xfda4 <parseNode+232>
```

And the offending line is specifically:

```
0000f6a6:   strd    r2, r3, [r12]
```

GCC generates code that uses an unaligned memory address with `strd`, which is not allowed in my architecture.

How can this issue be fixed?
Is this a compiler bug, or the code somehow confuses GCC?
Is there any flag to alter this behavior in GCC?

The aforementioned function belongs to an external library, so I cannot modify it.
However, I prefer a solution that makes GCC produce the correct instructions, instead of modifying the code, as I need to ensure that this bug will actually be fixed, and it is not lurking elsewhere in the code.

---

**UPDATE**
Following the recommendations in the comments, I was suspecting that the function itself is called with unaligned data.

I checked the whole stack frame, all previous function calls, and my code does not contain casts, unaligned indexes in buffers etc, in contrast to what I had in mind initially.

The problem is that the buffer itself is unaligned, as it is defined as:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint32_t var1;
    uint32_t var2;
    uint8_t var3;
    uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint16_t var4;
    // More variables here...
} HDLC_t;
```

(And later cast to `uint32_t` by the external library).

Swapping places between `var3` and `buffer` solves the issue.

The thing is that again this struct is defined in a library that is not in my control.

So, can GCC detect this issue between the libraries, and either align the data, or warn me of the issue?

Comment: How do you call the function? Any dirty casts there?

Comment: Perhaps you are calling the function with an unaligned `data` pointer? (I.e. a pointer not on a 4-byte boundary in this case.)

Comment: Otherwise, do a check like `volatile uint32_t my_debug_var = (sum >> 11) & 3;` before the loop, then check the value of that one. If it's a ridiculously large value, then you have an array out of bounds bug (which can topple the stack frame etc). Possibly the actual crash happens when you attempt to return from the function.

Comment: The address used here comes from the stack. Assuming this is the `data` argument, it might be misaligned (Your subset of the disassembly doesn't show if these were initially loaded with an `LDRD`, which would fail on misalignment, where a plain `LDR` might succeed if you have alignment checking disabled).

Comment: Indeed I am calling the function with a pointer to a uint8_t buffer, using an offset that may not be aligned. I am parsing a serial stream, so I cannot be sure where the encrypted part starts, in relation to the allocated buffer.

Comment: @FotisPanagiotopoulos Yeah so as expected, that's the bug, in the caller code. You need to update the question with that code, or we can close it as not reproducible.

Comment: Why don't you post the whole disassembly? Why does it read the destination pointer from the stack?

Comment: UPDATE: There must be compiler options that force structures to be aligned. What a poorly designed library.

Comment: Is the function call under your control? If so, you could call it via a wrapper function.

Comment: @IanAbbott Indeed, I can do that. But I am mostly interested in how to tell the compiler that this instruction is unsafe, since the same problem may also exist elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps it *would* make sense for the compiler not to generate ldrd and strd when `-munaligned-access` is in effect (which it is by default for ARMv7-M).

Answer (score 3):

> So, can GCC detect this issue between the libraries, and either align the data, or warn me of the issue?

Yes it can, it does and it must do in order to be C compliant. This is what happens if you run gcc at default settings and attempt to pass a `uint8_t` pointer (`HDLC_t` `buffer` member) to a function expecting a `uint32_t [2]`:

> warning: passing argument 2 of 'XTEA_decrypt' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

This is a constraint violation, meaning that the code is invalid C and the compiler already told you as much. See [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340) You could turn on `-pedantic-errors` if you wish to block gcc C from generating a binary executable out of invalid C code.

As for how to fix the code if you are stuck with that `struct`: `memcpy` the `buffer` member into a temporary `uint32_t [2]` array and then pass that one to the function.

You could also declare the struct member as `_Alignas(uint32_t) uint8_t buffer[100];` but if you can modify the struct you might as well re-arrange it instead, since `_Alignas` will insert 3 wasteful padding bytes.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way is to align `data` to 8bytes.
You should declare the array like:

```
__attribute__((aligned(8))) uint32_t data[2];
```

Comment: 32 bit integer arrays don't end up misaligned unless you do something strange. Like casting from character arrays or having them as members of an unpacked struct etc.

Comment: @Lundin Some old architectures require 8byte alignment for `strd` and `ldrd`

Comment: But surely not Cortex M3?

Comment: @Lundin OP clearly stated that unaligned access is not allowed in his architecture. He also mentioned that he's using an external library, and I think he's trying to link a library compiled for `M3` to his non-M3 project.

Comment: This is not working, as uint32_t data[2] is a function argument, and GCC does not allow me to add an attribute there: `error: alignment may not be specified for 'data'`

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE indeed unaligned access is not allowed. I am trying to use a statically linked library compiled for M3, on an M3 project.

Comment: @FotisPanagiotopoulos I don't get it. Why pass an array instead of a pointer?

Comment: Regardless, 8 byte alignment is not a requirement so this doesn't answer the question. M3 has alignment requirements on 4 byte basis save for the instructions listed here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/the-cortex-m3-instruction-set/about-the-instruction-descriptions/address-alignment

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE The compiler wouldn't have used `strd` if it could not assume 4 byte alignment is OK.