# How to do unaligned int store on ARM Cortex M4?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, cortex-m

How can C code take advantage of the Cortex M4's unaligned 4-byte store instruction?
`*(int*)p = x` mostly works, but occasionally I end up with something like this:

```
void Store(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
  *(uint32_t*)(p + 0) = a;
  *(uint32_t*)(p + 4) = b;
}
```

which `gcc` then compiles to:

```
00000000 <Store>:
   0:   e9c0 1200       strd    r1, r2, [r0]
   4:   4770            bx      lr
   6:   bf00            nop
```

which of course gives a `HardFault` because 8-byte stores must be aligned. Is there a way to write the stores so that gcc knows they can be unaligned? Is there maybe an unaligned int type, perhaps?

Comment: the strd alignment rule comes from armv7-m it is not limited to the cortex-m4

Comment: This is a gcc bug.  I feel clang is even worse. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82445  This was fixed for ARMv6.  Probably some cortex-a says strd is always allowed but they have made cortex-m the same.  I also feel this is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613802/arm-gcc-produces-unaligned-strd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinc you are using GCC, you can use a packed structure:

```
struct p { uint32_t u; } __attribute__((__packed__));

void Store(void *vp, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    struct p *pp = vp;
    pp[0].u = a;
    pp[1].u = b;
}
```

This generates:

```
Store:
        str     r1, [r0]  @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0, #4]      @ unaligned
        bx      lr
```

Note that you should consider the aliasing rules when doing this. If the destination is defined with a different type, storing the data with this structure type could require some workaround for that.

Comment: I like this answer because (1) it follows the style of the code I suggested and (2) the struct member looks and quacks like any other `uint32_t` (Except for the fact that unaligned access to it is allowed, and taking the address of a field would be unsafe. But I think gcc can be made to warn about that.)

Comment: @personal_cloud: If you attempt to put the address in a `uint32_t *`, as with `uint32_t *q = &pp[0].u;`, GCC warns “taking address of packed member of 'struct p' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]”.

Answer (score 2):

Your code (pointer punning )invokes undefined behaviour as you violating **strict-aliasing rules**.

You can't access one type by dereferencing tthe pointer of another type, except accessing via char pointer.

The best option is to use `memcpy` as it will always work

```
void Store(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    memcpy(p, &a, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(p + sizeof(a), &b, sizeof(b));
}

void Store2(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    struct 
    {
        uint32_t b32[2];
    } __attribute__((packed))*x = (void *)p;
    x -> b32[0] = a;
    x -> b32[1] = b;
}


void Store3(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    struct x
    {
        uint32_t b32[2];
    } __attribute__((packed))*x = (void *)p;

    *x = (struct x){a,b};
}

void Store4(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    memcpy(p, (uint32_t[]){a,b}, sizeof(uint32_t[2]));
}


void Store5(uint8_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
  *(volatile uint32_t*)(p + 0) = a;
  *(volatile uint32_t*)(p + 4) = b;
}
```

```
Store:
        str     r1, [r0]  @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0, #4]      @ unaligned
        bx      lr
Store2:
        str     r1, [r0]  @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0, #4]      @ unaligned
        bx      lr
Store3:
        str     r1, [r0]  @ unaligned
        str     r2, [r0, #4]      @ unaligned
        bx      lr
Store4:
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        strd    r1, r2, [sp]
        mov     r2, sp
        mov     r3, r0
        ldmia   r2!, {r0, r1}
        str     r0, [r3]  @ unaligned
        str     r1, [r3, #4]      @ unaligned
        add     sp, sp, #8
        bx      lr
Store5:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sYhdW8rK8

BTW **`clang`** is optimizing better:
https://godbolt.org/z/d11javbW9

```
Store:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
Store2:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
Store3:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
Store4:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
Store5:
        str     r1, [r0]
        str     r2, [r0, #4]
        bx      lr
```

Comment: implementation defined uses of structs are not to be relied on and should be avoided.  memcpy is the answer for attempts at such things.

Comment: as you pointed out the problem here is bad code, not what the compiler does with bad code. +1

Comment: @old_timer exactly what I wrote *"The best option is to use memcpy"*. I am just showing different options.

Comment: any coment silent DV-ter

Comment: `stm r0, {r1,r2}`  We expect the best from you mr. gcc, because you're awesome.

Comment: @artlessnoise `stm` does not support unaligned access. gcc is right

Comment: You are correct.  `strd` has an additional restriction that it must be 8byte aligned.  The `str` allows completely unaligned addresses on the Cortex-M.  clang keeps the `strd` under many different optimization levels for the cortex-m (and it depends on the clang version according to godbolt).  The casts are lies and will cause alignment issues (so good on that).  My concern is that there is some peephole issue still.

Comment: @artlessnoise  *"The str allows completely unaligned addresses on the Cortex-M"* No, it is not the truth. Cortex-M0 does not allow unaligned accesses at all

Comment: Yes, the Cortex-M0 is even more restrictive.  I was meaning Cortex-M3/4 which are more common and what the Q/A Is referring to and explicitly targeting in all of your examples.  It is interesting to see the compiler output when you target cortex-m0 in your examples.  gcc categorically produces the wrong result in the original case and does call mempy() in the others.

Comment: @artlessnoise in original case it does not have to produce the correct code as the original code invokes UB. Compiler is free to assume anything in  similar circumstances.

Comment: As, I believe, does the accepted answer. with 'pp = vp' which negates alignment.  As per old_timers comment 'the strd alignment rule comes from armv7-m it is not limited to the cortex-m4', where he (and gcc) lump cortex-m3/m4 as 'armv7-m' and the cortex-m0 stands outside (pedantically and technically).  Unfortunately ARM decided to alter the Cortex-M device load/store behaviours from ARMv6 which makes things a bit of a night mare for compilers.  Also, the next question will be why the unaligned stores take so much time. `void Store(uint64_t* p, uint32_t a, uint32_t b)` also works efficiently.

Comment: The best solution is actually to use the `uint64_t*` in the prototype as the caller must have an aligned pointer (and `strd` and other variants such as stm are fine). The compiler will check this and it will be efficient. The function API is broken and the hammer of memcpy() will fix the problem, but it is pretty in-efficient mapping of functionality to the underlying CPU

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches that worked are `memcpy`, and defining an unaligned int struct such as

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t d[4];
} my_uint32_t;
```

The result is then the desired separate 4-byte store instructions:

```
00000000 <Store>:
   0:   6001            str     r1, [r0, #0]
   2:   6042            str     r2, [r0, #4]
   4:   4770            bx      lr
   6:   bf00            nop
```